# Qt online installers list all repos

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I'm learning the Qt Installer Framework and creating repositories on a web server to be used by the online installers.  My problem is that even though each repository and installer is treated separately in the creation process, when I run any of the installers they list ALL the programs/repos on our server and check each of them for install.  It is of course possible to manually uncheck them, but really I want an installer specific to each program as different departments at my work use different programs and shouldn't have to go through the full list.

I don't understand why the installers are listing everything: each program/package has an individual repository on the server and an individual installer created using a config.xml, installscript.qs, and package.xml specific to that program.  Nowhere in any of those files is there a reference to any other program or repository, and I've used the repogen and binarycreator for each individual program rather than as a batch.  The only thing I can think of that might be affecting it is that the individual packages are subfolders under the same "package" folder in one unified installer framework folder.  I just point the repogen.exe and binarycreator.exe at the desired subfolder.  Could this be causing my problem?  Do I really need to have a separate installer folder with config and package subfolders for each program?

There's obviously a lot of moving parts to this so I'm not sure what specific code/info I should post, but please feel free to ask me for something that may be helpful and I will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the details of why, but the answer appears to be that every program needs its own installer folder.  It seems that everything under a single "packages" directory is consider a component of the same program, regardless of subfolders or arguments passed to the binarycreator.  So if you have multiple programs they each need their own installer folder with config and packages directories. That is unless you want a full list of available programs associated with each installer; and then what's the point of separate installers?